# Configuring Imported Self Signed SSL Certificate to SQL Server Express

Tags: ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate, sql-server-express, self-signed

I've created a self-signed certificate and configured with SQL Server Express. The encryption works fine on my PC.

When I export the certificate to another PC I can import fine and can see the certificate in MMC under `Personal > Certificates`.

However when I try to configure with SQL Server Express on the new PC, the certificate does not appear in the dropdown.

Any suggestions?

I have tried a few things suggested on other forums

- Making sure the private key is exported
- Making sure the certificate was created for local system (not user)
- Copy certificate into trusted certificates

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with programming.  Try SuperUser or ServerFault instead.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the properties for the certificate CN value. You will find that it has the "computer name" of the system that you created it on (which means "localhost"). This will not work when you copy the certificate to another system as the machine name will be different.